# Class Pointer reference inside of another Class defined below? (C++ 14, VS 2019)

Tags: c++, class

**Problem Summary**

I'm attempting to write a series of classes in C++ 14, that are all supposed to be inside of the same class, and have pointer fields that point to object instances of each one of the classes. They are all also supposed to have constructors that assign those fields, using arguments that are pointers to the other class instances. I'm running into a problem where I am unable to call the constructor with the pointer arguments. Below is an illustration of my problem:

Defined in **header** file:

```
class A;
class B;
class C;

class A {
public:
    class B {
    public:
        B(C* arg) {
            ptr = arg;
        }
        C* ptr;
    };
    class C {
    public:
        ...
    };
};
```

Runner code in **cpp** file:

```
A::C TEST_C = *new A::C();
A::B TEST_B = *new A::B(&TEST_C);
```

The line which initializes `TEST_B` with the constructor pointer argument call gives the following two errors in the VS 2019 compiler:

```
Error   C2664   'A::B::B(C *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'A::C *' to 'C *'
Error   C2512   'A::B': no appropriate default constructor available
```

**My Attempts**

The first error line got me thinking that I may need to change my forward class declarations to include their respective parent classes too, as such:

```
class A;
class A::B;
class A::C;
```

However, that appears to break the reference to class `C` completely, and any references to it in the header above it's definition treat it as an undefined reference (`Identifier "C" is undefined.`). It's as if there were no forward declarations at all.

Adding `A::` to each reference to class `C` in the rest of the header as such:

```
class A {
public:
    class B {
    public:
        B(A::C* arg) {
            ptr = arg;
        }
        A::C* ptr;
    };
    class C {
    public:
        ...
    };
};
```

didn't help either, instead the compiler tells me `Class "A" has no member "C".`.

However, one interesting thing that I did notice, was the fact that if I change the argument being passed to the constructor call for class `B`, to `nullptr`, that is:

```
A::B TEST_B = *new A::B(nullptr);
```

then the code gets compiled without problems. To me, that meant that this is most likely an issue with my forward class declarations, where the compiler sees that there are classes `B` and `C` declared, but it doesn't get to reading the actual content of the classes prior to attempting to reference them.

Is what I'm trying to accomplish here even possible with C++? Is there a way I should be doing this properly, that I'm not seeing?

Thank you in advance for reading my post, any help is appreciated!

Comment: The forward declared global classes and the inner namesake classes are different classes. Just move the forward declarations into the class.

Comment: Nothing to do with your question but ugh!? `A::C TEST_C = *new A::C(); A::B TEST_B = *new A::B(&TEST_C);` What's the point in allocating objects only to immediately dereference them and leak memory? You should be doing this `A::C TEST_C; A::B TEST_B(&TEST_C);` .

Comment: Any reason you need B and C to be declared within A? Why not declare them outside?

Comment: Unlike some other languages you don't need to always use `new` to create a class object. `A::C TEST_C;` by itself works just fine.

Comment: @273K Thank you for the concise and direct answer!

Comment: Thank you the rest for the helpful suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **problem** is that you've forward declared class `C` in global namespace instead of class scope `A`. This means that there are two different class named `C` one of which is declared to be in the global namespace  `::C` and the second one as an inner class `A::C`.

To **solve** this, just move the forward declaration of `class C` to inside class scope `A` as shown below:

**header.h**

```
class A {
public:
    class C;// forward declaration moved here inside class scope A
    class B {
    public:
        B(C* arg) {
            ptr = arg;
        }
        C* ptr;
    };
    class C {
    public:
        
    };
};
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/FFS-LfKB-)

---

Also, be careful about other logical bugs like memory leak(if any) in your program.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer, it was much simpler than I thought as it seems... I was just overthinking the problem after all.

One question:
Why would delcaring class B as "class A::B;" not work instead? Wouldn't that be the same as this?

Comment: @Runsva You're welcome. If you were to write `class A::B;` inside class `A` then that won't work because `A` is *incomplete* at that particular point. Additionally, in your given example we just need to forward declare class `C` inside `A` because class `B` has a data member of type `C*` and also have a parameter of type `C*`.

Comment: I meant outside, like I showed under the My Attempts section of my original post. Wouldn't declaring class C outside of Class A, as "Class A::C;" be the same as the answer?

Comment: @Runsva The reason that won't work is same. In particular, suppose we write outside class `A`, a forward declaration like: `class A::C;` then this won't work because `A` is incomplete at this point. The important point is that `A` becomes complete after the closing brace `};` of class `A`.

Answer (score 1):

```
class A {
public:
    class C;
    class B {
    public:
        B(C* arg) {
            ptr = arg;
        }
        C* ptr;
    };
    class C {
    public:
        ...
    };
};
```